# following imports which were working fine earlier are showing as unresolved symbols

Tags: java, android

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;
```

following imports which were working fine earlier are showing as unresolved symbols

Answer (score 0):

If you use IntelliJ, it can be related to IntelliJ Cache. Open IntelliJ and go to "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart..."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For **Android Studio**

Try:
**Cleaning the project or rebuilding the project.**

If that doesn't work,

And restarting doesn't work either,

Try `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate` and Restart.

And If the above solutions still not working then try:

Click on `Build` and click on `Rebuild Project` and then click `Tools → Android → Sync Project With Gradle Files`

This means you not only have to restart, but you need to invalidate those caches to restore.